# How to share ASP.NET Cookie with Angular 12 application

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc

How to share Asp.net cookie with Angular 12 application?

I have the following code in my ASP.NET application to create cookie:

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(".AspNet.SharedCookie", DateTime.Now.ToString())
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
                Secure = true,
                Domain = "localhost",
                Path = "/",
            };
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return Content("Welcome, new visitor!");
```

I am trying to read this cookie in Angular 12 application.

This is my code:

```
import { CookieService } from '../../../../node_modules/ngx-cookie-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) { }
  cookieValue: string = ""; 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger;
    this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('.AspNet.SharedCookie');
    console.log(this.cookieService.get('.AspNet.SharedCookie'));
  }
}
```

I am always getting cookieValue as empty?

Comment: Can you see the cookie in your browser's developer tools? If so, is it marked as HttpOnly?

Comment: You've set the Secure flag - is the page being loaded over a secure connection (HTTPS)?

Comment: You've also set the domain, is the page being loaded from `localhost`? Are you running from standard ports (80/443)?

Comment: yes. using default ports